# How to check EXIF extension is installed and enabled?

Tags: php, linux, exif

I am using Linux server. When I am trying to run `exif_read_data()` I am getting `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function exif_read_data()` .

Then I contacted the server provider and they say that EXIF extension is enabled in my server. but I am getting the same error.

I have performed the `Graceful Server Reboot several time`

I have tried to run

> if (function_exists('exif_read_data'))

and it is returning false. Also I have include `phpinfo()` in my page and nothing related to exif is listed in `Configure Command` portion.
But why did they say it is enabled for my site. Any other possibilities???

Comment: Have you tried to use:`if(is_callable("exif_read_data"))` ?

Comment: @ Rizier123 It is also returning false

Comment: Then I would contact your provider, since it doesn't seems like you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

While looking phpinfo(); output finds a section like this.
[exif exttension esction detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN98t.png)